# Qt qml - how can I handle the interrupt when the interrupt occurs in the MouseArea?

Tags: qt, qml, interrupt, signals-slots

```
MouseArea {
    drag.target: targetA 
    drag.minimumX: 22
    drag.maximumX: 40
    drag.maximumY: 22
    drag.maximumY: 50
    
    onPositionChanged: {
        console.log("onPositionChanged.....")
    }
    onExited: {
        console.log("Exited")
    }
}
```

In this an MouseArea in qml. If the onPositionChanged is interrupted, onExited is not worked. How can I know whether the interrupt occurs or not?

Answer (score 0):

onExited is only called, if a mouse button is pressed. You can set hoverEnabled to true to get informed even if there is no button. Here a small example of this:

```
MouseArea {
    hoverEnabled: true
    
    onExited: {
        console.log("onExited");
    }

    onPositionChanged: {
        console.log("onPositionChanged");
    }
}
```